# Azure config not showing up in portal

Tags: c#, azure, config

I have a web app I'm publishing on Azure. Somehow my web.config isn't showing up in Azure Portal.

Here's my config:

```
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
      </configSections>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="IDServizio" value="2" />
        <add key="IDServizio.DataSet" value="10" />
        <add key="IDServizio.Array" value="11" />
      </appSettings>
      <connectionStrings>
        <add name="DBConnString" connectionString="Data Source=xxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;Connect Timeout=50000"/>
      </connectionStrings>
<system.web>
...
</configuration>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: hopefully, its just a typo on your end, you do not have the closing configuration tag

Comment: yes, I didn't include the last part of the config

Comment: Where is that you are searching in Azure Portal for the web.config of web app? are you checking in Advanced Tools blade --> Go--> kudu -->Debug Console--> site/wwwroot/